How to get the following element with XPath?
I have HTML code like this:
<li>
   <span class="a">b</span>
     lorem ipsum
</li>

I want to get the text lorem ipsum, related to the span element.
I tried //following::span[@class="a"]/text(), in my opinion correct, as stated in other thread - but this didn't work for me.

Lorem ipsum actually belongs to the li element as the second text node, the first being the whitespace between the li and span elements.
Here's a quick XPATH that returns that value:
//span[@class="a"]/../text()[last()]
Caveat/Warning: Parsing HTML as an XML document may not work as HTML doesn't have to respect element nesting.

This xpath will get that text
normalize-space(//span[@class="a"]/following-sibling::text())


I'd do it slightly different than the other answers, but it's just personal preference that I don't like to go back up the tree (with ..) or use the following-sibling:: axis if I don't have to.
//li[span[@class="a"]]/text()[normalize-space()]

